# Why is my nodejs wildcard for app.get not working?

Tags: node.js, express

im using a express app to provide a vue.js produnction build.
the build uses the vue router.
if i want to call /home or /login the server responds wit "cannot get /home".

```js
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/index.html');
  next();
});

//mount router
app.use('/*', router);`
```

the root url "/" can be accessed normally.

Thanks in advance.

I tried using different Wildcards (like "+", "*" or /\ ) and arrays of urls.

EDIT:
this is the whole source code without the router:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist')));
app.use(express.json())

const port = 80;

const { Logger } = require('./src/logging/Logger.js');
const { Request } = require('./src/requests/requests.js');

//new logger instance
var log = new Logger();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/index.html');
});

app.post('/api/*', async (req, res) => {
    var request = new Request();
    request.callBackend(req.url, JSON.stringify(req.body), (rawResponse) => {
      const response = JSON.parse(rawResponse)
      res.status(response.status).send(response.content)
    });
});

//handel type 500 errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  log.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something went wrong!');
});

//init frontend server
app.listen(port, () => {
  log.info(`Vue App is served on port ${log.highlight(port)}`);
  log.info('Directory for vue app: ' + path.join(__dirname, '../../dist'));
});
```

The `app.post('/api/*', (req,res)...` works absolutely fine
what i need is an `app.get('/*', (req, res) => {});`
but this doesnt work.

Comment: For starters, don't call `next()` when you've already sent a response with `res.sendFile()`.  That probably isn't the cause of "cannot get /home", but it is something that needs to get fixed anyway.

Comment: thx, removed it.

Comment: If you want all incoming requests to go to your router for it to examine, just do this: `app.use(router);`.

Comment: Is this `app` the SAME `app` that you're calling `app.listen()` on?  You should only have one `app` object.  You can have many routers, but all routers have to be hooked into the one `app` object that you called `.listen()` on.

Comment: yes its just one app object, im trying your solution now

Comment: i edited the question to provide you more information

Answer (score 0):

This route:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/index.html');
});
```

matches every single URL and sends a response.  So, no routes defined after this will ever be active.

What I would suggest it to change that to this:

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, '/index.html');
});
```

Then, it's only matching the root URL and other URLs can be matched by other route handlers.

Comment: thats not working as well. I think I will just build the app.get for every route

Comment: @CØDƐX - What exactly isn't working when you use this?  What URL?  Which request handler isn't matching that URL?  We need more specifics than "not working".

Comment: if i access the vue app at localhost, `localhost/` its working perfectly fine. as soon as i want to access a vue route `http://localhost/home` i get the order page just as i want it. if i refresh the page while being on `/home` i get the response 'Cannot GET /home'

Comment: @CØDƐX - You don't show a route for `/home` so why should there ever be such a page loaded?  You should only use URLs that you have explicit routes for.  You shouldn't be using wildcards that all serve the same content as that messes up search engines, allows users to use wrong URLs, etc...   If you have no route for `/home`, it should give an error the first time you attempt to load that page.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your help, i build th routes now server-sided, it is much easier as well.